# Formatar string na View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Existe alguma forma de formatar uma *string* (retornada de uma consulta) diretamente na *View*, para mostrar a primeira letra maiúscula e o restante minúscula?

Ex: No C# eu posso utilizar o *TextInfo.ToTitleCase* para isso.

```
string title = "war and peace";

TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
title = textInfo.ToTitleCase(title); //War And Peace
```

Na View eu sei que existe o *ToUpper()* e o *ToLower()*, mas existe um *ToTitleCase* ou algo que faça a mesma função?

Se tento utilizar diretamente na view:

```
    @model PortalRH.DomainModel.Entities.Usuario
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="right"><strong>Endereço:</strong></td>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff"> @Model.NmFuncionario.toTitleCase</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Recebo um erro falando que que existe este método:

> 'string' não contém uma definição para 'ToTitleCase' e nenhum método de extensão.

Lembrando que este valor retorna do banco de dados, então necessito tratar o mesmo.

Comment: Você tentou usar o `ToTitleCase` e não funcionou?

Comment: Quando eu tento usar o ToTitleCase na view, eu recebo erro de sintax

Comment: Lembrando que por JS, ou outro script, também atende. Só gostaria de saber se é possível retirar co controller.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e poste todas as informações relevantes sobre isto. Se o erro é de sintaxe precisamos ver como está usando e exatamente qual é o erro. O ideal é deixar a *view* com o mínio de processamento possível, sempre que for possível é melhor colocar processamentos no modelo ou no controlador.

Comment: @bigown eu editei a resposta com um pequeno exemplo da View.
Estou querendo saber se existe como fazer na View, pois acho que tornaria um pouco mais rápido, como se adicionasse um ToUpper(). Por favor, me corrija se eu estiver errado.

Comment: toTitleCase é um método, então @Model.NmFuncionario.toTitleCase não vai funcionar. Você só acessaria assim se fosse uma propriedade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ideal é colocar estas coisas no modelo ou no controlador quando pertinente. A visão deveria ser reservada apenas para montar a apresentação. Se você precisa ter o dado com as primeira letras capitalizadas então deveria ter uma propriedade, provavelmente no modelo, que entregue o dado desta forma para você. Isto é o mais correto. Não estou dizendo que fazer o mais correto sempre é desejável.

Eu consideraria criar uma propriedade assim:

```
public string TitleCaseNmFuncionario {
    get {
        return System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(this.NmFuncionario);
    }
}
```

Aí na visão você poderá usar:

```
@Model.TitleCaseNmFuncionario
```

Mas se quiser fazer tudo na visão, é possível mas tem que chamar o método com a sintaxe correta:

```
@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(Model.NmFuncionario)
```

Se isto não funciona do jeito que você deseja mas o código que deseja funciona em outro lugar, traga o código que funciona para a *view*, assim:

```
@{
    var textInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
    this.Write(textInfo.ToTitleCase("war and peace"));
}
```

Outra forma de facilitar o uso deste algoritmo é criar um método utilitário, assim basta você chamá-lo sem ter que escrever um código longo que não é ideal em uma visão:

```
namespace Extensions {
    public static class StringExtensions {
        public static string ToTitleCase(this string texto, string cultura = "en-US") {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultura)) {
                cultura = "en-US";
            }
            var textInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultura, false).TextInfo;
            return textInfo.ToTitleCase(texto);
        }
    }
}
```

Aí você pode chamar de forma bem simples na *view*:

```
@Model.NmFuncionario.ToTitleCase()
```

E é possível passar como parâmetro deste método uma cultura diferente da americana. De fato você pode mudar o método de extensão para deixar por padrão a cultura que você pretende usar mais como a "pt-BR".

Para usar este método teria que colocar no início `@using.Extensions`. Se você quiser disponibilizar automaticamente para todas as páginas, o que é desejável na maioria dos casos deve colocar a seguinte linha dentro da *tag* `<namespaces>` no arquivo `web.config` do seu projeto:

```
<add namespace="Extensions" />
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/FormatStringView.cs).

Mas eu ainda prefiro fazer no modelo.

Comment: Continua trazendo igual está salvo no banco de dados.

Comment: eu chamei o *@using.System.Globalization* e coloquei o restante do campo e funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: É uma outra forma de fazer.

Comment: A forma no model eu não conhecia, vou aplicar ela aqui. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Renilson, uma outra sugestão seria criar uma classe de extensão, ou seja , assim você podera criar diversos metodos extendendo as classes existentes:

Por exemplo, crie uma class estatica com uma metodo estatico:

```
  namespace MVCApp.Extensions
  {
     public static class StringExtensions
     {
        public static string ToTitleCase(this string valor, string cultura = null)
        {
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultura))
              cultura = "en-US";

           TextInfo textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
           return textInfo.ToTitleCase(valor);
        }
     }
  }
```

Pegue a namespace "MVCApp.Extensions", e adicione no webconfig da PASTA DAS VIEWS e adicione ao nó namespace

```
     <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MVCApp.Extensions" />
     </namespaces>
```

Agora builda o projeto, fecha e abre o visual studio
Pronto! agora voce pode usar em qualquer lugar do seu sistema, seja classe ou razor, o metodo ToTitleCase() em qualquer string:

[image: Utilizando o metodo na view]

Lembre, qualquer string do seu projeto agora pode utilizar este metodo

Sendo opcional informar a cultura.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @LucasRoselli. Realmente este método será bem útil em meus projetos.

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar!!! Para futuras respostas, o que faltou na minhas resposta para ela ser a melhor resposta ?

Comment: Eu ainda não tive tempo de testar sua resposta em meu contexto, para averiguar se realmente é melhor que a marcada anteriormente. Por este motivo não marquei como a melhor ainda.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo pela resposta!!! Aguardo qualquer duvida!! Mas acredito que ela seja melhor por sem global, ainda mais sem necessidade de replicar o código como o sugerido anteriormente, alem de não alterar o seu modelo.

Comment: @RenilsonAndrade Mas a solução é a mesma que eu dei, se for uma questão de encapsular em um método de extensão, eu posso colocar na minha resposta também.

Comment: @bigown a dúvida inicial de minha questão já foi sanada, eu estou para analisar a resposta do LucasRoselli apenas para fins didáticos, pois era uma alternativa que não conhecia. Mas se você modificar sua resposta, deixo ela como a melhor, para ajudar alguém que possua uma dúvida similar.